# Django "Singleton model" to store user settings

Tags: python, django, singleton, settings, single-instance

I am building a web app with Django. I would like to be able to store final user settings for my app. For now I am using a model Settings that contains all what I need for the app. 
It seems ok but I don't think that's the right way to do it because I could have a second row in my database and I don't want it.
I though about using a file but it is not as easy to manage as a table in a database.

Could someone help me with that please ?

Thank you ! :)

Louison

Comment: Can you share the current approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're interested in managing settings for your django app through an editable, easy to update interface.

A popular existing approach to this is implemented by [django-constance](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance). It can use your database or redis to store the settings, and it makes them editable through the django admin. You can [look at the documentation here](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

[image: django-constance admin example]

Ultimately, the approach of using a database table to store configuration settings is fine. The issue of having one row can feel odd though, so django-constance's approach is to use a key/value design where each individual configuration key has its own row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the `user` field as `unique=True`. This is basically what a [**`OneToOneField`** field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) does. This thus means that a user has *at most* one related record:

```
from django.conf import settings

class UserSettings(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …
```

If you thus aim to insert a second row for the same user, it will raise an error (given the database enforces such constraint, but nearly all databases do this). Furthermore if you use a form, Django will do such validation as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using admin for that then you can create your admin class as you wish and set has add permission to false. and you can override changelist_view to redirect to the the only predefined row as follows:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:erpapp_rescompany_change' , kwargs={'object_id': ResCompany.objects.all().first().pk}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late to the show here, but why not try a post_save signal?

**models.py**

```
class AppSettings(models.Model):
    setting_1 = models.IntegerField()
    setting_1 = models.IntegerField()
```

**signals.py**

```
from someapp.models import AppSettings
@receiver(post_save, 
          sender= AppSettings,
          dispatch_uid="delete_any_new_records"
          )

def delete_any_new_records(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if AppSettings.objects.all().count() > 1:
        instance.delete()
```

The first record will be allowed, but all subsequent attempts to add new records will be deleted.